# What model does apache tika use internally - TensorflowRESTCaptioner

Tags: apache, tensorflow, deep-learning, apache-tika

Iam working on an image captioning tool and came across the apache tika

[TensorflowRESTCaptioner](https://tika.apache.org/1.18/api/org/apache/tika/parser/captioning/tf/TensorflowRESTCaptioner.html)

and would like to now which model does it use internally and how good are the results when compared with the state of the art right now in the market

[pythia - BUTF - FacebookResearch](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pythia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Apache Tika [changelog](https://tika.apache.org/1.17/index.html) I came to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2262) feature request for image captioning. There, the author stated that they used Google

> 'show and tell' neural network

mentioned in [this](https://ai.googleblog.com/2016/09/show-and-tell-image-captioning-open.html) blog post.

Also, [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06647) is a link to the paper if you want to compare it to the current state of the art methods.